# Android SDK Not Updating Packages

Tags: android

Running Windows 7.  Just installed Android SDK. Trying to get the packages with SDK manager revision 16, but get these errors after about 2 or 3 minutes (very slow):

```
Fetching  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Failed  to fetch URL //dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Reason: Connection to //dl-ssl.google.com refused 

Fetched Add-ons List
Successfully Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml

Failed to fetch URL //dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
Reason: Connection to //dl-ssl.google.com refused 
Done loading packages.
```

I have no proxy.

I have unchecked the "force https...to http..." setting.

I can get the two URLs to load in IE9.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

SOLUTION: I got the list to finally load. I had my firewall turned off, but the issue was an expired version of Zonelabs software. After I uninstalled Zonelabs, the list of packages loaded and installed.

Comment: You should add answers as an answer, not to the question.

Comment: Tom -- I would have but as a new member I could not. As I attempted to answer my own question, stackoverflow told me I had to wait 6 hours before answering my own question.  Strange but true.  So I will add it now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the list to finally load.  I had my firewall turned off, but the issue was an expired version of Zonelabs software.  After I uninstalled it, the list of packages loaded and installed.