# Android studio connection reset error?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I have updated android studio 2.2.2 recently. Now i got connection reset error when i check sdks and adding dependency to build.gradle. I have no idea about this. guide me to remove this error.

[image: image1]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019858/android-sdk-manager-wont-update-connection-to-https-dl-ssl-google-com-refuse

Comment: did you checked the above link/

Answer (score 6):

Try adding mavenCentral() inside the buildscript.repositories enclosure, like so. put error log for eject answer

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()   // This repo should have the gradle plugin
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }
```